# Static Library added as sub-project vs static library added as target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, ocunit

First of all I'd like to say that I'm pretty new to this topic so I'm a bit confused on some general aspects of how it works.
Basically I'm working on an iOS project which has two targets, one is the app itself which I'm developing and it is a front-end iOS client, one is a static library which the former developer used to define classes belonging to a back-end framework.

Both the files of the app itself (the client I'm working on) and the static library (the back-end framework) are in the same xcode project bundle.
Even If I've never done the "setup procedure" of the static library anything seems to be working just fine on compilation.

Now the question is: I'm setting up unit tests because I'd like to start developing new features adopting a Test Driven Development approach, so one of the things I was struggling on was if I had to generate or not two separate test targets, one for the iOS app and one for the static library (since they're two separate targets), ore use one single test target for both the static library and the iOS App.
So, reading on the internet to find a solution I discovered that, as even Apple suggests [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html) , a common approach is to add the static library as a "sub-project" of the app project.

I'm just asking myself why and what is the difference with my current situation (one project, to targets, one of it is the static library). Are there any drawbacks? Should I reorganize the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience agrees with Apple and the common approach. I'd suggest making the framework a subproject. (I've had some issues finding headers, but that's my lack of mastery over Xcode, not a flaw in the process.)

Set up unit tests on each project, independently. This way, your tests are true to your objective with a framework: You've successfully decoupled the framework from the parent project entirely.

If you write the all of the unit tests in the parent project, what happens when the framework is needed in another project? You've got two choices. You can not test the framework, or string along the original parent. Do the right thing and split up your tests.

I've got an open source framework that I built, called [SpiffyKit](https://github.com/MosheBerman/SpiffyKit), that has a parent project called SpiffyTester. (I admittedly didn't unit test much, because it's all UI and no logic.) It may serve as a good example of a starting point.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you with the decoupling thing, but the point of my question was slightly different, I'd like to know why decoupling with a sub-project rather than with different targets each one with different files linked against.
I'd like to know why one is better than another because I find adding things via a sub-project a bit tricky, is it just a conceptual thing like: "a day you might want to add that library to another project too, so it deserves a separate project to live in" or there are other issues related to the bundle maintainence and distribution processes that I'm not ware of?

Comment: I think that both of those are valid reasons. You may want to add the library to another project, or you may want to share that library without sharing the rest of the code. The atomic unit of Cocoa projects is the Xcode project. It's a good idea, for all of the reasons mentioned, to stick to that unit.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your needs you can use [Pods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods), static or adding it to the project. If you add a library as a "subproject" is useful when you are working on the 2 projects at once. For example if you add something new to the library you just compile the library and voila you have access to the new library in your project. However if you just link the static library you will have to open the project for the library then build then replace it in the library and add the new headers witch is a lot of setup work.

Comment: CocoaPods is not appropriate here.

Comment: Since he is asking about this i consider he should know all the ways to add libraries/code to the project getting extra knowledge and a bit thinking never heart anybody.

Comment: I already knew about cocoa pods, and sometimes I've used it in some of my projects, but this is not the case. It would add extra complexity, the library I'm adding to my project sonsists of code we're still working on and gets updated very often, the code should be ready and editable and we should be able to test it quickly.